# Get the first row from Jquery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have jquery Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.70:81/MobileService.asmx/FetchData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
        var Tabels = msg.d;
        $.each(Tabels, function(index, table) {

        alert(table[0]);-------> I am trying to get the row using index, it retuns nothing

        var table_data='<div class="table"';
        table_data +=" onclick='test()' >"+table.Name +"</div>";
        $('#itemGroup').append(table_data);
        });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
        alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

I want to find the first value of the result. How can I do that? index returns the row number(ie. index of the row), but how can I get the first row value?

Comment: did you try Tabels[0]

Comment: and you can check `if(index==0)` then its first object

Comment: Yes I tried tables[0], it returns [object Object].

Comment: If condition helped me. :-)

Comment: are you sure data comming in  `var Tabels = msg.d;` try to check the length of Tabels object using `alert(Tabels.length);` its '`Tabels` not `tables`

Comment: ohh good at least something helped :)

Comment: Yes I tried tables[0], it returns [object Object]. so its first row  try to JSON.stringify(Tables[0]) it will give you result :)

Comment: use table[0].Name it will work

Comment: alert(Tabels.length); return the correct length in my case it returns 13.

Comment: JSON.stringify(Tables[0]) doesn't work.

Comment: @cracker,  table[0].Name does not work. I get table[0] is undefined

Comment: Just a question. Why is it `var Tabels = msg.d`. Can it not be `var Tabels = msg`?

Comment: @CronasDeSe I was using a webmethod from a web service and had to use msg.d as the response was in 'd'. If you are using a web api then it will most probably be in msg itself.

Comment: I see thanks. I actually tried it. This solution worked for me. Minus the `d` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(index==0) did a trick.

```
if (index==0)
{
  alert(table.Name);// fetch row value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$.each(msg, function (index, itemData) {
   var valuesof = itemData.YourValues;
});
```

Comment: take all the value and set return so it will take the rows of 0 position.

Comment: I want 1st as well as all other values. But only for 1st value I need to do some computing.

Comment: it will give you all the values one by one you can track it by using int i; at o position and then increment it